# Finding CPU utilization in c++ using libproc

Tags: c++, cpu-usage

I have been using libproc library in c++ to find the CPU utilization but I cannot find any examples to retrieve some fields.

1. I want to calculate the cpu usage of a process/thread?
2. To find the memory usage of a process/thread?

If any one knows please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantaneous CPU percentage is commonly desired, but is not tracked by the kernel and is therefore not available anywhere procps can read. Tracking a percentage has to be implemented in the application by taking a snapshot, waiting a little while, and taking another snapshot to learn the utime+stime spent during the interval. This is the reason why top shows all CPU percentages as 0.0% when it starts, and corrects them on the next interval. procps provides a convenient place to store the CPU percentage, but does not implement it in the library.

Taken it from [here](http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2011/02/listing-processes-with-libproc.html), and there is some more information on how to implement it there.